# get key and value of array via underscore each

Tags: javascript, arrays, underscore.js, each

I would like to loop through an array and get the key and value of it. This is what I'm doing, but I don't get any output. What am I doing wrong?

```
let regexes = [];
regexes['some.thing'] = /([^.]+)[.\s]*/g;

_.each(regexes, function(regex, key) {
    console.log(regex, key);
});
```

Comment: An array in Javascript has numeric indexes. If you want to iterate an object you can do it in vanilla with: `for(var key in yourObjectOrArrayLike){console.log(key + ' - ' + yourObjectOrArrayLike[key]);}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are assigning a property to the array. Lodash is attempting to iterate through the numeric indices of the array, but there are none. Change the array to an object and Lodash will iterate through its enumerable properties:

```
let regexes = {};
regexes['some.thing'] = /([^.]+)[.\s]*/g;

_.forEach(regexes, function(regex, key) {
    console.log(regex, key);
});
```

Alternatively, if using an array is necessary, simply push the value onto it:

```
let regexes = [];
regexes.push(/([^.]+)[.\s]*/g);

_.forEach(regexes, function(regex, i) {
    console.log(regex, i);
});
```

Comment: _.each has been deprecated in favour of _.forEach. See https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#forEach

Answer (score 1):

`_.each` iterates through the indices of the array. You are adding a *non-numeric property* to the array object. Your array is empty and `_.each` callback is not executed. It seems you want to use a regular object (`{}`) and not an array:

```
let regexes = {};
```

Now `_.each` should iterate through the object *own* (by using `hasOwnProperty` method) properties.

Answer (score 1):

You are using array and adding a property to it which is not valid .Use object for it

```
let regexes = {};
regexes['some.thing'] = /([^.]+)[.\s]*/g;

_.each(regexes, function(regex, key) {
    console.log(regex, key);
});
```

Comment: It is entirely valid to add a property to an array in this fashion. However it doesn't achieve the desired outcome in this case. :-)

Comment: Yes i know ,but it is not recommender and has very little use